# dd command does not work

Tags: linux, iso-image, dd

I'm creating a Kali Live image with `dd` and I got this issue:

```
$ dd if=kali-linux-2017.1-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=512k
$ dd: erreur de lecture 'kali-linux-2017.1-amd64.iso': Valeur trop grande pour le type défini de données
```

In English: `dd: reading error 'kali-linux-2017.1-amd64.iso': the Value is too large for the defined data type`.

What can I do?

Comment: I know too little (yet) to write a good answer but [this seems relevant](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type).

Comment: @Kamil Yes, could be a file size problem (the ISO is >2GB) however I wonder what Linux distro from the 3rd millenium doesn't support files >2GB?

Comment: Thank you to tell me why,

Now, the question is how to fix it ?

Comment: This is `EOVERFLOW`; you can find more information e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981085/whats-the-semantic-difference-between-erange-and-eoverflow . It could also be that the underlying filesystem has a problem with files >=2GB, but not likely.

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs? What does `strace dd if=kali-linux-2017.1-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=512k` say? (The last few lines, including the `EOVERFLOW`)

Answer (score 0):

For `dd`, `bs` is the **b**lock **s**ize. And a block size of 512 kilobytes doesn't exist in real devices, which is why the internal integer type for it doesn't have enough bits to represent it.

So either use a proper value, like `bs=512` (that's bytes without a `k`, not kilobytes), or just use

```
cp kali-linux-2017.1-amd64.iso /dev/sdc
```

because you don't need blocksize defined access for USB sticks (though it doesn't hurt).

Comment: Using a bigger block size doesn't change correctness for disks and USB sticks (unlike what it did for tapes), but it is definitely beneficial when it comes to copying speed. I typically use `bs=1024k` (1 Mebibyte)

Comment: @MarcelWaldvogel: `cp` *should* optimize that on its own, but I never actually tested ... my harddisks are pretty slow anyway.

Comment: Current GNU cp uses 128kiB buffer size for "standard" operations (was 32kiB until 2012 and 64kiB until 2014, so the "optimization" is driven by someone patching `ioblksize.h` every few years. http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/ioblksize.h;h=6cbd8b4e1addec15031832fb51007084a219bba4;hb=HEAD